# VBA Excel Game - Testing

Tags: game, vba, excel

My brother bet me that I couldn't make a game in Excel. The code is all over the place and buggy in parts. But I would appreciate it if anyone would give this game a go.

The music and the code has all been made by me, but the artwork was found online and I can't claim any of it is mine (although a few bits were photoshopped to make it work for me).

There's still a few bits of the game that don't work 100% but it shouldn't crash on you.

[Full code](https://drive.google.com/#folders/0B6BOCseXW1yZREtPT2FYTWhkQ0U)

There's an installer or the zip file - it's probably best to just use the zip file.

```
Sub dogame()

Application.Visible = False

loadedgame = False


Do



    fminitScreen.Show
    playgame



    If loadedgame = False Then

        loadplayer
        fmNameHim.Show
        fmChooseWeapon.Show

            If Worksheets("options").range("B3").value = True Then

                fmrules.Show

            End If

        fminside1.Show

    ElseIf loadedgame = True Then

        Dim obj As Object
        Dim obj1 As Object

        Load fminside1
        Load fmoutside
        Load fmupstairs

        For Each obj In UserForms

                If obj.Name = player.formname Then

                            loadedgame = False
                            obj.Character.left = player.left
                            obj.Character.top = player.top
                            obj.Show
                            Exit For
                Else
                    If obj.Name = "fmMusic" Then

                    Else
                        Debug.Print "unloaded form" & obj.Name
                        Unload obj

                    End If

                End If


            Next obj

    End If

    fmranking.Show
    Set player = Nothing

Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: nice name for a *dog* : `ame` ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Procedure names should start with a verb that says what the procedure does.

> ```
> Sub dogame()
> ```

That doesn't say much; "do" is as general as it gets. Also, by convention, procedure names should be `PascalCase`, so `Sub DoGame()` would follow that.

You're not showing where `loadedgame` is declared, but if it's declared, I suspect it's a `Boolean` variable, at module level. If `dogame` is the only procedure that uses this variable, then `loadedgame` should be *scoped* to that procedure, and declared as close as possible to its usage:

```
Sub RunGame()

    Dim loadedGame As Boolean
```

`Boolean` variables get initialized with a `False` value, so if `loadedgame` is scoped at procedure level, this line isn't needed:

> ```
> loadedgame = False
> ```

It's a very, very good idea to always declare all variables you're using. One way of forcing yourself to do that, is to specify `Option Explicit` at the top of every code module you're writing - whether it's a form's code-behind, a class module, or a standard module: with that option specified, VBA will refuse to compile your project if an undeclared identifier is used anywhere.

---

Your indentation is somewhat broken in the inner `For` loop, and I strongly recommend indenting the entire procedure's body too:

```
Sub RunGame()

    '<~ indented

End Sub
```

The `If Worksheets("options").Range("B3").Value = True Then` condition doesn't need to be indented - it's at the same level as the previous `fmChooseWeapon.Show` line.

---

VBA module members are `Public` by default, but in other languages it's `Private` by default; it's always best to be explicit about access modifiers:

```
Public Sub RunGame()
```

I think there's way too much vertical whitespace. There shouldn't be 2 empty lines in a row.

---

`Boolean` values can be used as a condition's expression - `If [Boolean expression] Then` can also be `If [Boolean value] Then`, so this:

> ```
> If loadedgame = False Then
>     'block A
> ElseIf loadedgame = True Then
>     'block B
> End If
> ```

Is better written like this:

```
If Not loadedgame Then
    'block A
Else
    'block B
End If
```

...and best written like that:

```
If loadedgame Then
    'block B
Else
    'block A
End If
```

Positive conditions are always easier to mentally process; don't be afraid to reverse the `If` and `Else` blocks to reverse a negative condition! Also, a `Boolean` can only ever be `True` or `False`, so there's no need to evaluate the `False` condition if you've already checked the `True` condition - the `ElseIf` block can become an `Else` block without altering the logic.

---

This part is weird:

> ```
> If obj.Name = "fmMusic" Then
>
> Else
>     Debug.Print "unloaded form" & obj.Name
>     Unload obj
>
> End If
> ```

If there's nothing to execute in the `If` block, only in the `Else` part, then you need to reverse your condition:

```
If obj.Name <> "fmMusic" Then
    Unload obj
    Debug.Print "unloaded form" & obj.Name
End If
```

Notice I've moved the `Debug.Print` call *after* the `Unload` instruction - this way the *immediate* window will not say "unloaded form xyz" *before* the form is actually unloaded. Alternatively, you could edit the message to say `"unloading form " & obj.Name & "..."` - the idea is to avoid telling confusing lies if anything goes wrong with that `Unload` call. That said, `obj` is a very bad name to use - why not call it `form` or `window`?

---

The procedure is quite long - I'd consider extracting smaller private procedures out of it, perhaps starting with the two branches in the `If loadedgame` condition. A procedure should do one thing (and do it well), so as to have as few reasons to change as possible. Having more specialized procedures helps making your code more manageable, too.

Lastly, I suspect this is all written in a standard code module; I would encapsulate the game logic inside a class module, and have the `dogame` procedure instantiate an object of that type and call some `Run` method. The entire `dogame` procedure/macro could then possibly look like this:

```
Public Sub RunGame()
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler

    Dim game As New GameLogic
    game.Run

CleanExit:
    Exit Sub
ErrHandler:
    Debug.Print "An error has occurred: " Err.Description
    Resume CleanExit
End Sub
```

Comment: ++ usually `Bool/Boolean` should start with `IsSomething` :) Microsoft doesn't always follow that principle but it's good if we do it makes code analysis a lot easier :)

Comment: Download it and play it there are tons on classes and more. I want to learn more and i appreciate all your comments and don't take offence to any of it and will only learn and grow. I need experience from people you like to guide me into the future.

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to go down through the code line by line. I may be harsh at times, but remember, I say these things so that you might become a better programmer.

---

> ```
> Sub dogame()
> ```

The sub name is a bit hard to read. I personally like the [.Net capitalization standards](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229043(v=vs.110).aspx) where methods are PascalCased. Isn't `DoGame` easier to read? Also, get into the habit of explicitly declaring [scope](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/scope.aspx).

> ```
> Application.Visible = False
> ```

I like that you're hiding the Excel instance from the user, but what happens if an error occurs? Without an error handler to regain control and make Excel visible again, you'll end up with an instance of Excel that you can only kill via the task manager.

> ```
> loadedgame = False
> ```

Remember those naming conventions I mentioned earlier? Variables should be camelCased. So, `loadedGame`. However, I think it's easier to read as `isGameLoaded`.

The next thing I want you to do is start using `Option Explicit` in all of your [vba](/questions/tagged/vba) code. It forces you to declare all of your variables. This will turn typos into compile time errors. It's wonderful. Trust me, [just do it](http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/option-explicit.html).

Lastly, booleans default to false, so if you declare the variable using a `Dim` statement, there is no need to explicitly set it to false.

---

To recap so far:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub 
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler

    Dim isGameLoaded As Boolean

    Application.Visible = False

    '...

    Exit Sub

ErrHandler:
    Application.Visible = True

End Sub
```

---

Which brings us to the `Do` loop. Friend, that is just awful. You've intentionally created an infinite loop. Once the `DoGame` is called, it never exits. ***Never.*** The only way I can figure to kill this is to open the task manager and kill Excel.

What you should do is have a `While` loop that exits when the game is over. For example, consider this code where `GetGameState` is a function that returns a boolean.

```
Dim gameOver As Boolean

While Not gameOver

    gameOver = GetGameState

End While
```

---

> ```
> fminitScreen.Show
> playgame
> ```

Again with the capitalization. This is hard to read. Not much else to say other than if you *must* use Hungarian notation for your user forms, then you should at least use Microsoft's recommended notation. `fminitScreen` should be `frmInitScreen`. But ***really*** `InitializationScreen` or `StartScreen` would be much better names. (I was going to provide a link, but it seems that MS has scrubbed that document from the face of the Earth...)

---

Skipping ahead a bit, there's this.

> ```
> If Worksheets("options").range("B3").value = True Then
> ```

First, we have no clue what this value ***is***, other than it's ***some*** option of some kind. I recommend creating a well named function to retrieve this value.

Secondly, the statement can be simplified by omitting `= True`. This is essentially what happens right now.

> ```
>  Worksheets("options").range("B3").value = True
> ' get value from worksheet 
> True = True
> ' is true equal to true?
> True
> ' enter if statement
> ```

That's why you can write this like this.

```
If Worksheets("options").range("B3").value Then
```

Same thing here. Simplify it.

> ```
>  ElseIf loadedgame = True Then
> ```

```
ElseIf isGameLoaded Then
```

---

This is bad. Could these names be more generic?

> ```
>     Dim obj As Object
>     Dim obj1 As Object
> ```

What really makes this terrible is the type doesn't even give us a hint because you've declare them as [generic objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264754(v=office.15).aspx). You could literally stuff any class instance you wanted to into those variables.

It looks like you're using `obj` to iterate the `UserForms` collection

> ```
>    For Each obj In UserForms
> ```

So why not declare it as a `UserForm`???

```
Dim obj As UserForm
```

Or better yet

```
Dim frm As UserForm
```